# IcedCoffeeScript Sourcemaps in Node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, coffeescript

I'm using iced-coffee-script with node.js. I haven't been pre-compiling my .coffee files but instead am just requiring the iced-coffee-script package from my .js application startup file. Does anyone know of a way to trigger sourcemap creation in this situation so that https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support will work?